# How to create a Javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I see a lot of Javascript frameworks created recently since I've been learning web development (http://www.infoq.com/research/javascript-frameworks-2015). Do you know what kind of knowledge you need to know in order to create a Javascript framework in particular or any framework in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a JS (or any other kind of) framework isn't something done easily, but some of the steps include:

1. Find a niche where no framework exists yet or doesn't cover a specific use-case, and where you have good knowledge of the problem space
2. Design and implement an easy to use (and, if required, future-proof) API
3. Publish it, e.g., on GitHub and advocate for it with a website or through blog posts
4. Maintain it

Hence, you'll need to know how to design good APIs, reasonable JS knowledge to build them and patience.

**Note:** while the initial fun starts with building out something, releasing and maintaining an actual framework is far more complex and requires time and effort - especially to build a community and once these users start requesting additional features, or your initial design considerations fall short of the new use-cases imposed by real-world usage. You can always build something and publish it to NPM, but be aware that maintaining a project in the open source community involves more than "writing code", and deprecating or deleting a framework/package can [yield surprising results](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/).